# php permission access denied when try to copy in IIS

Tags: php, iis-10

I'musing php7.2 and running below code to copy a file from one folder to another on my local server(using wamp server) and its working,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$filename =  "roomTemp.csv";

copy($filename, 'reports/'.$filename); //copy($from,$to);
echo "done";
```

unfortunately, same code did not work on IIS server(IIS-10, windows 10) and showing below error **Warning: copy(roomTemp.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**.

based from my research, there's **safe_mode** need to be turned off from my php.ini, but I couldn't found it.

others also mention about windows permission, and I've granted all user to full control access.

please help, thanks.

**Edit**

my working dir is : "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bms"

Comment: You need provide more info on folder structure you are working on, which is the file containing your code, is it in same folder with "roomTemp.csv" or not?

Comment: yes..roomTemp.csv in same folder as my code, and I've create folder named **reports/** as a new folder for roomTemp.csv to be pasted in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit permissions and add iusr 
show image:
[IIS Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABRUY.jpg)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).